# How to get portlet context in config (Liferay)?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'd like to access the Context of the portlet in config mod (in my implement of `ConfigurationAction` interface).

I try since hours to get the same Context in my `ConfigurationActionImpl.processAction(PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)` as I have in my `doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)`, but without any good result.

In my `doView()`, I can access my portlet Context using `getPortletContext()` (same as `getPortletConfig().getPortletContext()`) and `renderRequest.getPortletSession()` (it's **NOT** the same Context instances), but I don't know how I can access one of those objects from my `processAction()`.

Can somebody help me, please ?

Comment: As a workaround, I use a **static** class variable (HashMap<String, Bean>). It feets my needs, but I'm not sure it's a best practice.

Comment: Any member on a portlet class - static or not - is typically an indicator for an underlying problem. (I think this assumption holds in your case). It might be easier if you ask your question in a way that does not ask for "how to get to the solution that I thought of" - rather ask for "I want to achieve X - how can I best do this"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried the way you talk about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087613/how-to-share-data-between-all-users-of-a-portlet-instance), but there is no real solution to this problem.

Comment: Like by other question, my recommendation is don't put whole Beans to context, preferences or some else. If that requirements is necessary - then you need a cache layer - and that is something major difficulty )) Then describe the whole requirements.

Comment: My need is this :
From the data in preferences, I compute some beans that will be usefull for my portlet. The computing of those beans depends on the content in the portal, and I don't want to make this on every viewing of the portlet becaus eof the time it would take. The resulting beans are not really big, but I don't want to store that data in preferences (I don't want to parse it). I think you're right : I need a cache, and that is exactly what I made with my static variable. But don't you think a cache layer would be too much for my needs ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I ended up using:

```
PortletBag portletBag = PortletBagPool.get(portletId);
DispatcherPortlet portlet = (DispatcherPortlet)portletBag.getPortletInstance();

PortletContext pCtx = portlet.getPortletContext();
```

In case you want to compute the `portletId`, you can do this:

```
String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "portletResource");
String portletId;
if (portletResource.contains("_INSTANCE")) {
    portletId = portletResource.substring(0, portletResource.indexOf("_INSTANCE"));
} else {
    portletId = portletResource;
}
```

As a side note, I want to mention that I needed it in order to be able to get the Spring `ApplicationContext` of the portlet, which I did with this:

```
PortletContext pCtx = portlet.getPortletContext();
ApplicationContext portletAppContext = (ApplicationContext)pCtx.getAttribute(FrameworkPortlet.PORTLET_CONTEXT_PREFIX + portlet.getPortletName());
```